# Calculating extra attrib. in 3D Matlab's regionprops

Tags: matlab, structure, regions

I have used 'regionprops' to identify regions after a volume segmentation. I need to know the pixel values within each region. The result from 'regionprops' include 'PixelList'. For example, the first region's pixel subscripts in my volume are:

```
regions(1).PixelList:


   100    27    73
   100    26    74
    99    25    75
```

There are more than 4000 regions. It takes time as well as being inelegant to go through all the regions in a loop.

How can I get the 'PixelList' for all the regions and calculate the Mean, Max, Min, etc. for every region without using a loop.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the intensity image, as well as the label mask to `regionprops`:

```
>> p = regionprops( bw, intensity, 'MaxIntensity', 'MeanIntensity' );
```

Read more about it in the [docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html)

Comment: I am afraid it is not possible for 3D volumes. It is only for 2D.

Comment: @user1641496 once you have `bw` and `intensity` you can `reshape` them to 2D and apply `regionprops`. Note that while this trick is good for `'MeanIntensity'` and `'MaxIntensity'` this trick will **fail** for other properties, such as `'WeightedCentroid'`.